# Multibranch Pipeline. Unable to configure specific branch configuration

Tags: github, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I am configuring the multibranch pipeline. I found out there are two options for configuration in the multibranch pipeline.

One is in the multi-branch pipeline initial dashboard [image: Multibranch pipeline initial]

Another is like this inside of any branch. [image: inside branch]

This is my configuration on the multibranch pipeline from initial dashboard configure.[image: Configuration inside multibranch pipeline]

And inside the specific branch, I configured the following but was unable to save it. [image: configuration inside specific branch]

So, is there any way I can configure this and save it so that I can trigger for each branch based on the push/merge to GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, sorry. 
The configuration is at the multibranch (i.e. repo) level.

In fact, the configuration menu item for the branch is "VIEW configuration" and doesn't have a Save button for that very reason. It's just helps you review the configuration for that branch (it's not terribly useful IMHO).
So you can't customize per actual branch.

If you really need to do that, you need to write your jenkinsfile to have branch-dependent logic in it.

Comment: How can I share you my configuration so that you can help my requirement.

Comment: I would suggest you now ask a separate question

Comment: Just to let you know, I have solved the issue.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: But my new requirement is, can I define environment variables in Multibranch pipeline like we do for other jobs in Jenkins so that my variables are not exposed?

Comment: @Manish_ could you share how you solved your issue? Or the link to the question where you solved it. Thanks.